# Ajax popup causes screen to re-load using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, popup

I am using the code from *[How to create a stunning and smooth popup using jQuery](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/)*. When I click the button to activate the [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) popup, it does appear, but the page is reloading on the button click.

How do I get around this?

Comment: can you post the code of the HTML involving the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your modal wired up to an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) button? If so, this will be set to postback on a click. Perhaps wire the modal to a regular [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) button instead?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing your code, but whatever link/button you are using to launch the dialog, make sure it is returning false from its click event handler (or submit event handler on a form)

Comment: The click event from the sample code is missing the return false statement as stated by @jayrdub.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your button is a post back button. You might want to change that configuration so that it does not automatically post back.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) button control, it wanted to post back, so I created an update panel with the `AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID=[my button id]`.

So the code to make it all work (with loading the jQuery library) is as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div id="button">
                <asp:Button ID="Save1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Save1_Click" />
        </div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Save1" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <div id="popupContact">
            <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
            <h1>Title of our cool popup, yay!</h1>

            <p id="contactArea">
                Here we have a simple but interesting sample of our new stuning and smooth popup. As you can see jQuery and CSS does it easy...
                <br/><br/>
                We can use it for popup-forms and more... just experiment!
                <br/><br/>
                Press ESCAPE, Click on X (right-top) or Click Out from the popup to close the popup!
                <br/><br/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```